# IntelliJ "Build>Make" not available

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I'm trying to implement spring boot devtools (auto restart to be exact), but I'm struggling even at making the projekt as - there is no make in my build menu. It's configured in my menu configuration, but it's just not visible. Even in my "Run/Debug Configurations" I'm not able to select "Make" as a before launch activity.

If someone has more info in how to get auto restart to work with a docker infrastructure I'd be happy as well.

Comment: Could you share your project?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The confidentiality agreements I had to sign had more chars than the code itself :-/

Comment: Could you at least provide a screenshot demonstrating the issue?